# Как в ангуляре правильно создавать элементы, которые не исчезают при смене адреса?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spa

Делаю приложение на ангуляре (не на втором). Есть навигация, которая есть на каждой странице и есть остальная часть, которая зависит от адреса.

```
<nav>...</nav>
<div ng-view> ... </div>
```

Все хорошо, при переходе по ссылкам в меню, основная часть перерисовывается, а навигация остается. Но вдруг появляется необходимость сделать страницу, на которой мне не нужна навигация. Как быть?

Как вообще быть, когда мне нужно, чтобы при переходе по страницам, один элемент оставался статичным (например плеер), но есть страницы, на которых он не нужен?

Comment: `ng-if`, `ng-show`/`ng-hide` - скрываете не нужные элементы

Answer (score 1):

Использовать ui-router вместо классического - он позволяет делать вложенные view.

Либо выносить общие элементы во внешний контроллер и обеспечивать в нём (возможно, через сервисы) логику отображения этих элементов.